# Watchkit: Is it possible to add an image behind a WKInterfaceLabel?

Tags: swift, background-color, watchkit, wkinterfacelabel

I am trying to add an orange circle with a number (my number will change depending on certain circumstances) inside it in my WKInterfaceGroup like the image below.

[image]

However, it appears you can't change WKInterfaceLabel background color. The only solution I can think of is to add an image behind the label. So how can I achieve this (if it is possible)? Is there another way to make this work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to:

1. Put the Label into a Group.
2. Center Align and Position the layout of the Label
3. Set the Group to a Fixed Width and Height.
4. Set the Corner Radius of the Group equal to 1/2 the Width (height should be the same)
5. Set the Group to Background Color to the color you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the label to a `WKInterfaceGroup` and set its background image property. Or, you can create pre-rendered template images and use [setTintColor:](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceImage_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WKInterfaceImage/setTintColor:) to color them.